# 'javac' cannot be found problem

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a Java application hosted on a remote tomcat instance that executes a bat file which contains the following line

```
javac filename.java
```

I receive the following error :-

> 'javac' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I have set the path in the environmental variables. I tried running the same bat file on the machine, it works(which means there is nothing wrong with the path). But running it through the application gives the error. What might be the problem?

Comment: Where did you set the environment variables? Are you sure the apply to the bat file when executed by Tomcat?

Comment: you could set the PATH variable in your bat file.

Comment: Just a trivial idea - sure, that the machine, that runs the remote tomcat has a Java SDK installed? Otherwise there's no javac

Comment: @Andreas_D :- dont be kidding me :)

Comment: Note that modern Tomcats carry their own compiler with them.  Consider letting Tomcat do the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the correct path in your environment does not fix the path in the environment of the running tomcat process. If you changed the path in the system settings, a tomcat restart (or system reboot) probably solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once you add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the PATH var on the remote machine (assuming you have `%JAVA_HOME%` set there), you will need to run up a new cmd window for the new PATH to be available.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the classpath for the user who is executing tomcat, not only for your login user.

Comment: This is not a classpath problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the JRE installed, and not the JDK, you'd be able to run Tomcat but there wouldn't be a javac.exe.  Go to JAVA_HOME/bin and see if there's a javac.exe.  If not, you have the JRE installed, and you'll have to go get the JDK.

Just curious - why is your Tomcat app calling javac.exe?  Are you creating classes on the fly?  If yes, why would you not be generating byte code using ASM instead?